# Renaming a folder for each download

Tags: php, download

**EDIT:** We allow our product download after submitting a simple form.

To avoid the owners of "illegal websites" learning where our product downloads are located, I was thinking about renaming the download folder after every download.

How can I do this in PHP?

Comment: Uhm... can you please clarify your goal and purpose? On first read it sounds slightly ludicrous.

Comment: to make doubly sure your products are safe, hide them under the floorboards, they _never_ look under the floorboards....

Comment: If your paid software is available from your server through a direct link you deserve people downloading it using that link without paying.

Comment: I improved my question, we don't have a direct link but out there they always manage to discover where files are located and to download them directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution so far is the following: http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Simple-and-Secure-PHP-Download-Script-with-Limits-Tutorial/.

Thanks to all of you for directing me to this approach.

Answer (score 8):

Instead, verify an authenticated session and then stream the download via PHP.

Then if any *illegal website* tries to download your file, they will find they need to be authenticated first.

Comment: Something more specific to my purpose?

Comment: What do you mean with _stream the download via PHP_?

Comment: @devdept Essentially what [NathanD's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108157/renaming-a-folder-for-each-download/6108264#6108264) is doing.

Answer (score 2):

Don't rename the directory. It will break if multiple users download the file simultaneously. Instead serve file via PHP like:

```
<?php
// We'll be outputting a PDF
header('Content-type: application/pdf');

// It will be called downloaded.pdf
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');

// The PDF source is in original.pdf
readfile('original.pdf');
?>
```

Comment: Interesting, in this way nobody knows where the file is located on the download server?

Comment: +1 Under the assumption that this script also checks whether the user is allowed to download or not. Otherwise, this is exactly the same as a direct link, since the URL won't change (@dev).

Comment: @devdept - yes, it can even be put outside web root directory.   @deceze - agree, user must be validated before this code is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, - you can do it by using [rename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) PHP function, but what a strange approach? You better customize access settings for files which can be accessed via HTTP request and which can not. Let just registered users download files and identify real users from robots using user session cookies and, probably, add captcha if those file are so significant.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution might be to do a PHP system call to create a temporary softlink to your installer, and remove that softlink after a fixed amount of time.

But indeed, it seems you've got the wrong idea when it comes to safeguarding your installer.

Comment: How do I create a softlink to our installer?

Comment: Well, assuming you are running a linux server, using the ln command. But then again, sessions are a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing personal, but it's not most clever idea.
Check `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` - if this variable is **not** empty and not contains address of pre-download page, redirect user to some your pre-download page.

**edit:** checking `HTTP_REFERER` is not 100% protection against bots, but other methods (such as authentication) can be more annoying for users.

Also, sessions or cookies (with temporary token) can be used.

Comment: `HTTP_REFERER` cannot be trusted. In some user environments, it is possible that it will be always empty, even though the user had no malicious intentions.

Comment: @bazmegakapa, yes, you're right, that's why I wrote about sessions and cookies also. Checking the `HTTP_REFERER` it's just most easiest way.

Comment: @OZ_: In what cases the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is empty?

Comment: @bazmegakapa, when user has come from another site (not from pre-download page), or when it is bot, or when in user's browser turned off option 'Send referer'.

Comment: @devdept Robots cay not be so clever to pretend to be humans and thus not pass HTTP_REFERER (robots developers will figure it out really quickly!). Some browsers in some cases don't pass the referer too.

Comment: @OZ_ Or it can even be a proxy or something like that that the user does not even know about. An empty `HTTP_REFERER` does not mean anything, nothing should be restricted if the referer is empty.

Answer (score 1):

A good way is to use a combination of .htaccess & key

```
.htaccess
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/([a-z0-9]+/i)$ serve.php?file=$2&key=$1 [NC,L]
```

After someone purchases your file set a key and ip in there customer account in mySQL send them the link to download via email (`http://yoursite.com/key1234567/your.pdf`) note they can only download once

person clicks download

then with serve.php

you check the key against there ip in there account and mark as downloaded

```
sql check on ip and key match


if($allowedToDownload===true){
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');

    // It will be called downloaded.pdf
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');

    // The PDF source is in original.pdf
    readfile('hidDen_ArEa/'.basename($_REQUEST['file']));
    }
```